# Google's cloud SDK doesn't return `createTime`

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to list info about some instances using cloud sdk, but for some reason the `createTime` field is not returned. Any idea why?

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --format="table(name,createTime)" --filter="name:florin*"
NAME                         CREATE_TIME
florin-ubuntu-18-playground
```

This should work according to this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `gcloud compute instances list` does not show the instances creation time by default. But the [gcloud `--format` flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) can change the default output displayed.

`gcloud compute instances list --format="table(name,creationTimestamp)"`

It is also possible to retrieve the instance creation time from the [gcloud compute describe command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe#GCLOUD-WIDE-FLAGS):

```
gcloud compute instances describe yourInstance --zone=yourInstanceZone | grep creationTimestamp
```

Or:

```
gcloud compute instances describe yourInstance --zone=yourInstanceZone --flatten=creationTimestamp
```

Comment: Actually this works `gcloud compute instances list --format="table(name,creationTimestamp)" --filter="name:florin*"`, I was asking for `createTime` when it seems `creationTimestamp` was the correct field name. Thanks!

Comment: @gplayer, Thanks for coming back! I have updated the answer.